# Make tableView cell receive all gesture inputs?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableView inside a tableView Cell.  Table view is not scrollable. I want the user to be only able to interact with the tableViewCell behind, is this possible? Currently, the tableView is block user from interacting with the tableView cell behind it. Any way to prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Disable user interaction on the table view in so that the touch events are passed to the parent